# Any substitution for GridLayout for API<14?

Tags: android, view

I want to add buttons on screen , by 2 per row, using addView method.
This is very easy with GridLayout but this excludes everything below 4.0 android.

Any suggestions to do it on older API?
The only way I see is to add a horisontal LinearLayout with a pair of buttons , but may there be a simpler way?

Comment: Add the **support-library v7** to add a compatible GridLayout.

Comment: oh great, didn't know it supports GridLayout! Make it an answer - I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [official docs page](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html):

**v7 gridlayout library**

This library adds support for the GridLayout class, which allows you to arrange user interface elements using a grid of rectangular cells. For detailed information about the v7 gridlayout library APIs, see the android.support.v7.widget package in the API reference.

This library is located in the /extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout/ directory after you download the Android Support Libraries. This library contains user interface resources. To include it in your application project, follow the instructions for adding libraries with resources.

---

The Gradle build script dependency identifier for this library is as follows:

com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.+
This dependency notation specifies the release version 18.0.0 or higher.